# Solr search query for dynamic fields indexed

Tags: dynamic, solr, field, solrnet

I am implementing the solr search in my project .
I have one question regarding how do i search a dynamic fields that is created in a solr index 
Eg:-  this is the tag that is formed in the index

And I am  trying to search from solr using this query Employee_* = 172

Please help me in this if the way of searching is incorrect.

Answer (score 15):

In your queries, you need to define exactly what concrete fields you want to search, e.g. `Employee_a`, `Employee_b` (or whatever dynamic fields you've used). You can't search in all dynamic fields by using wildcards in a field name in queries.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a work-around :

- create a (static) copyField
- copy the dynamic field into the (static) copyField
- query the copyField

Your schema.xml could look like this:

```
   <dynamicField name="Employee_*" type="string" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <field name="emp_static"  type="string" indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <copyField source="Employee_*"    dest="emp_static"/>
```

Now you can query solr via :

```
select?q=emp_static:"172"
```

You can even tweak it and not store/index the dynamic field (as you might not query on it ... )