# solr doesn't fetch dynamic fields

Tags: solr, cassandra

I am using solr to retrieve results from a cassandra table.

**Table structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  field1 uuid,
  field2 text ,
  bfield blob,
  cstdta_<text, text>,
  PRIMARY KEY (field1)
);
```

**Table content**

```
INSERT INTO mytable  VALUES ( 62c36092-82a1-3a00-93d1-46196ee77204,"test", { 'f1'  : 'La Vita E La Felicita', 'f2' : 'Michele Bravi' });
```

I am able to retrieve the results when queried directly using devcenter. But on using solr query, the dynamic field is not returned.

**Solr query Response:**

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 1
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 1,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [
      {
        "field1": "62c36092-82a1-3a00-93d1-46196ee77204",
        "field2": "test"

      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is the scheme.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<schema name="autoSolrSchema" version="1.5">
<types>
<fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.TextField" name="TextField">
<analyzer>
<tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>

<fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.UUIDField" name="UUIDField"/>
<fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.BinaryField" name="BinaryField"/>
</types>
<fields>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="field1" stored="true" type="TextField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="field2" stored="true" type="TextField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="bfield" stored="true" type="BinaryField"/>
<dynamicField indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="cstdta_*" stored="true" type="TextField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="cstdta_stc" stored="true" type="TextField"/>
<copyField source="cstdta_*" dest="cstdta_stc"/>
</fields>
<uniqueKey>resid</uniqueKey>
</schema>
```

I added the copy field following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17693890/2098335). But it doesn't seem to work.

**UPDATE:**

As user3398164 pointed out I needed to insert  customdata inside the dynamic field in a specific format. In my case, I had to insert using this query:

```
 INSERT INTO mytable  VALUES ( 62c36092-82a1-3a00-93d1-46196ee77204,"test", { 'cstdtaf1'  : 'La Vita E La Felicita', 'cstdtaf2' : 'Michele Bravi' });
```

Now I am getting the desired result:

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 1
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 1,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [
      {
        "field1": "62c36092-82a1-3a00-93d1-46196ee77204",
        "field2": "test",
         "cstdtaf1":"La Vita E La Felicita",
         "cstdtaf2" : "Michele Bravi"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: try with this <copyField source="cstdta_*" dest="cstdta_stc"/>

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti, it was a typo. Edited the question

Comment: why multiValued="false" for the field cstdta_stc...? multiValued=true|false

True if this field may contain multiple values per document, i.e. if it can appear multiple times in a document

Comment: Do a restart after the changes and re-index as well...

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti tried setting multivalued to true and reindexing. Still no change in results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Sharun Try inserting the data as mentioned in the below link
https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.6/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchDynFlds.html

***Copied from the reference site:***

> In CQL, to define the map collection column, use the same base name
>   (no asterisk) as you used for the field in the schema.xml. For
>   example, use dyna_* in the schema.xml and dyna_ for the name of the
>   CQL map collection.
>
> Use type text for the map key. For example:
>
> CREATE TABLE my_dynamic_table (   . . .   dyna_ map,   . .
>   . ); Using CQL, insert data into the map using the base name as a
>   prefix or suffix in the first component of each map pair. The format
>   of the map using a prefix is: { prefix_literal : literal,
>   prefix_literal : literal, . . . }
>
> For example, the CQL map looks like this: 'dyn_' : {dyn_1 : 1, dyn_2 :
>   2, dyn_3 : 3}